# How do I find what my DPI setting is in OS X?

Tags: macos, mac, mac-mini

I don't have a retina display, and display settings doesn't show any relevant info. How can I see what my DPI in OS X is?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily calculate DPI on sites like this: https://www.sven.de/dpi/

Comment: Nice, however those are "CSS pixels", which aren't always accurate. For instance, visiting on my phone shows a width of 360px, but in fact my phone has a physical width of 1080px. I need true hardware DPI.

Comment: you can edit your actual hardware DPI in the input fields.

Comment: I have added support for retina displays by querying `window.devicePixelRatio` so the correct screen resolution should now appear on retina devices.

Answer (score 0):

You can calculate Pixels Per Inch using this [PPI/DPI calculator](https://pixelsperinchcalc.com/) tool!

Hope it helps!